# Pasar valor de DataGrid a un textbox de otro formulario

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Buen día,

Me quede estancado en lo siguiente quiero pasar de un formulario el valor del `grid` a un campo `textbox` de otro formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello estaba usando lo siguiente en el evento del grid:

```
private void DgvBuscar_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IList<DataGridCellInfo> celdas = e.AddedCells;
            FrmDocumental.valortxt = celdas[0].Item as string;
        }
```

Y en mi Formulario principal asigno el valor del evento anterior `cmbDestinatario.Text = valortxt;` Pero no he podido avanzar para que el txt tome el valor.

Agradezco sus aportes.

Comment: en donde haces la asignacion cmbDestinatario.Text = valortxt?

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder, lo hago en el `cs` del formulario principal

Comment: si.. pero en donde? estas en wpf pero no pareces que uses binding, que seria la solucion simple y elegante. Vos le estas pasando a FrmDocumental.valortxt, un valor. ahora, esa variable, despues como se la pasas al form?

Comment: No lo he probado con binding, puedes regalarme un ejemplo por favor?

Comment: internet esta lleno, no es algo que se haga solo con un ejemplo, necesitas un tutorial muy completo al respecto. ahora, siguiendo con tu problema, que haces con valortxt del otro lado? porque asignarle algo a una variable no implica que se va a mostrar en tu form

Comment: no estas usando MVVM, no ? porque esto seria mucho mas simple si usas el patron: publish/observer

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar un valor de un form al otro debes contar con la instancia de ese form

Imaginemos estas en el form que tienes el grid

```
private FrmDocumental frmDoc = null;

public void button1_click(...)
{
   frmDoc = new FrmDocumental();
   frm.Show();
}

private void DgvBuscar_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IList<DataGridCellInfo> celdas = e.AddedCells;

    if(frmDoc != null){
        frmDoc.setRemitente(celdas[0].Item as string);
    }
}
```

La idea es que la instancia del form hijo este definida de forma global.

En el form hijo que tiene el textbox deberias definir

```
public void setRemitente(string remitente)
{
    txtRemitente.Text = remitente;
}
```